# Facebook plugin load

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've added Facebook like button plugin on my website everything works perfectly, except one thing: the plugin loads after the rest of the page is fully loaded and it doesn't look properly. There is a script template for that plugin:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I tried to add js.async = true; But it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: This code is specifically written in a way so that it does not block the rest of your page content. You could theoretically embed the SDK so that it loads synchronously - but that is really not recommendable, because if Facebook is “down” (and that does happen from time to time), it would block loading all further content on your site, too.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I haven't considered Facebook service failure. Thanks for your advice!